# Difference between "mythical" and "mythological"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

What is the difference between *"mythical"* and *"mythological"*? I find these two interchangeable.
Also, please give some examples.

Comment: http://www.talktalk.co.uk/reference/dictionaries/english/data/d0082457.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **mythological** is from an accepted tradition of mythical stories, like the Roman or Hindu or Navaho religions.
- **mythical** is anything fantastic or imaginary or fictitious.

So 'mythological is a subset of 'mythical'. The myths of the Roman religion make up Roman mythology. They are considered mythical, as are the Easter Bunny or Tooth Fairy. One could say that -any- fiction (like say 'Jane Eyre') is mythical because it is fiction, but there is the need for the idea of the fantastic for 'mythical' to apply.

Answer (score 3):

Chambers has...

**mythical** *adj* 1 relating to myth. 2 imaginary; untrue.

**mythology** *noun* (mythologies) 1 myths in general. 2 a collection of myths, eg about a specific subject. 3 the study of myth or myths. **mythological** *adj* relating or belonging to mythology.

**myth** *noun* 1 an ancient story that deals with gods and heroes, especially one used to explain some natural phenomenon. 2 such stories in general; mythology. 3 a commonly-held, false notion. 4 a non-existent, fictitious person or thing.

So *mythical* is related to a [particular] ancient story. "The Minotaur is a mythical 
beast."

*Mythological* is related to a collection of mythical stories or the system of belief they describe. "In Greek Mythology, Hera was the wife of Zeus, the greatest god."

Answer (score 0):

A mythical creature is one whose existence has not been proved, and hence considered non-existent. The Yeti is a mythical creature. (Maybe it will be found one day.)

A mythological figure is one described in mythology, whose existence cannot be proved.
However, we do not say mythological figures never existed, because that cannot be proved either.

Mythologies generally eulogise the characters so we treat them in reverence, often as gods. Mythical creatures are mostly considered bizarre and feared.

Comment: So, are you saying both, mythical and mythological, creature are non-existent but we cannot prove that they never existed. So, where's the difference?

Comment: @rudra The difference is in 'have not' and 'cannot'. A myth could one day be (dis)proved -- like I said about the Yeti -- but a mythological figure is forever what it is, real for those who beleive, virtual for others.

Comment: @rudra Obviously you have read my answer in a haste. It does not say as you contend.